# Road closed to through traffic

Tags: grammar, prepositions, signage

What is the grammatical analysis of the sign "Road closed to through traffic", specifically the prepositions "to through"?

Comment: This is the international road sign meaning "[No Through Road](https://www.archersafetysigns.co.uk/prod.php?prod=5633&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtvPjBRDPARIsAJfZz0pwgMXZMGY-12fCYwwU2mX-JZ1N_FZrr12Zw62pUpClCCQK1R9STl8aAst0EALw_wcB)". The ancient one in Britain said just that. It means the road is closed to "through traffic".

Comment: The sign is used when there is no (other) outlet for a given set of roads. But the OP's issue seems different, not that traffic literally can't go through, it's just not welcome.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer My point was merely that "through road" was a similar expression to "through traffic".

Comment: I see. My misunderstanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Road *subject*

closed *verb*

to *preposition*

through (or thru) *adjective describing "traffic"*

It means the road is open to vehicles going to houses or shops on that road, but is closed to traffic passing along the road to other destinations.

Comment: From the stress on "thru" in "thru-traffic", you can tell that "thru" is not an adjective, but rather the first part of a compound.

Comment: @GregLee In my British accent, Greg, I would change the stress from "_through_ traffic" to "through _traffic_" depending on context. I'd be less likely to find the need to say "through _traffic_" than, say, "heavy _traffic_" (as in I'm stick in heavy _traffic_") but I'd still treat "through" as an adjective.